# Counting Unique Entries in Column Where some are upper or lower are not combining

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, count

I am new to Postgres and having a little difficult with text columns.  I have a 'city' table with other columns, however the city column has cities with both lowercase and uppercase entries. Counting produces separate counts, and I am not sure how to fix this.

My `city` table sample data:

| uID | state | city (character varying) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TX | austin |
| 2 | MN | minneapolis |
| 3 | MN | MINNEAPOLIS |
| 4 | TX | austin |

I want to create a simple test query, but it comes back like this:

| city | total count |
| --- | --- |
| austin | 2 |
| minneapolis | 1 |
| MINNEAPOLIS | 1 |

This is what I have, but this did not work, I also tried using lower() and upper() on city to have all lower or upper, and also in the count itself but neither works:

```
SELECT 
    city, count(*)
FROM 
    table
GROUP BY 
    1
ORDER BY 
    count DESC
```

Comment: Why does `UPPER` or `LOWER` not work? Works fine [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=e9dba4ab9ce45924488c16410f6d6be7)

Comment: I am not sure it simply won't work no matter what I do (this is in pgAdmin).

Comment: Issue could be data-specific. Please post actual or close to actual data (not very simplified mock-up) and actual results (not just *it won't work*).

Comment: I think I figured it out, I am using nested CTEs and I was not applying the upper or lower to the first cte where it resides

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `upper` or `lower` to convert the strings into a standard case, and from there count the records. Keep in mind that spaces might screw things up when aggregating by text columns. Use `trim` to avoid that:

```
SELECT upper(trim(city)) AS city, count(*) 
FROM t 
GROUP BY 1;
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=30d94dd8bed1844ca3917acc5ca58b39)

Comment: I think this did the trick, it seems like there were spaces that I could not detect before.

Comment: request completed